# How to read specifically formatted data from a file?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm supposed to read inputs and arguments from a file similar to this format:

```
Add  id:324  name:"john" name2:"doe" num1:2009 num2:5 num2:20
```

The problem is I'm not allowed to use fgets. I tried with fscanf but have no idea how to ignore the ":" and seperate the string ' name:"john" '.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use fgets?  Is it a homework assignment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know for sure the input file will be in a well-formed, very specific format, `fscanf()` is always an option and will do a lot of the work for you.  Below I use `sscanf()` instead just to illustrate without having to create a file.  You can change the call to use `fscanf()` for your file.

```
#define MAXSIZE 32
const char *line = "Add  id:324  name:\"john\" name2:\"doe\" num1:2009 num2:5 num3:20";
char op[MAXSIZE], name[MAXSIZE], name2[MAXSIZE];
int id, num1, num2, num3;
int count =
    sscanf(line,
        "%s "
        "id:%d "
        "name:\"%[^\"]\" "  /* use "name:%s" if you want the quotes */
        "name2:\"%[^\"]\" "
        "num1:%d "
        "num2:%d "
        "num3:%d ", /* typo? */
        op, &id, name, name2, &num1, &num2, &num3);
if (count == 7)
    printf("%s %d %s %s %d %d %d\n", op, id, name, name2, num1, num2, num3);
else
    printf("error scanning line\n");
```

Outputs:

> Add 324 john doe 2009 5 20

Otherwise, I would manually parse the input reading a character at a time or or throw it in a buffer if for whatever reason using `fgets()` wasn't allowed.  It's always easier to have it buffered than not IMHO.  Then you could use other functions like `strtok()` and whatnot to do the parse.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this is what you want ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[200];
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", str) == 1)
  {
    char* where = strchr( str, ':');
    if(where != NULL )
    {
      printf(" ':' found at postion %d in string %s\n", where-str+1, str); 
    }else
    {
      printf("COMMAND : %s\n", str); 
    }
  }      
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

If output of it will be

```
COMMAND : Add
 ':' found at postion 3 in string id:324
 ':' found at postion 5 in string name:"john"
 ':' found at postion 6 in string name2:"doe"
 ':' found at postion 5 in string num1:2009
 ':' found at postion 5 in string num2:5
 ':' found at postion 5 in string num2:20
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to extract John,Doe,2009 etc and store them in a linked list with unique ids. I don't have any problem with the rest of the program I just can't figure out how to extract the correct strings and integers from the file. Should I use something else instead of scanf?