# Read input txt files and format it in c

Tags: c, text, input, format

I have a input file that has different content and length each line.
Every line represents a command.

```
in
cr foo   //create file "foo"
op foo   //open it with index 1
wr 1 x 60   //write x in index 1("foo") 60 times
wr 1 y 10   //write y in index 1("foo") 60 times
sk 1 55     //such and such...
rd 1 10
dr
sv disk0.txt

in disk0.txt
op foo
rd 1 3
cr foo
cl 1
dr
```

I have looked at this answer, but it still not helpful for my question.
    [How to read specifically formatted data from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689747/how-to-read-specifically-formatted-data-from-a-file)
I really need help of how to read this input file correctly in order to perform different commands.
The command may contain integers, or it main only have one character, I don't know how to deal with this text! Please help

Comment: Do you know what is the maximum number of words the can appear in a command?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `fgets()` to read till end of line.
2. Please make a point that `fgets()` comes with a new line char.
3. Break the line to tokens using `strtok()` with space as delimiter
4. Use the tokens accordingly.
5. Use `strtol()` to deal with integers