# Reading mobile data(strings and numbers) from file in C

Tags: c, file

I have a file with data in the following format:

```
/*Number          Date    Time        Status    Call_duration(in minutes)   */  
9893575103  22-09-2016  12:32:01    incoming         2
9893575102  22-09-2016  12:44:05    outgoing         3
9893575101  22-09-2016  12:59:23    missed           0
9793575103  22-09-2016  13:30:32    outgoing         9  
9723575103  22-09-2016  14:44:44    incoming         4
```

I want to be able to reliably read this data into a C program and then manipulate the data once it's been parsed.

I tried to store data in a linked list after reading it from file using scanf:

```
struct Node {
  struct node *queue;
  struct node *front,*rear;
  int num[10];
  int dd,mm,yy,hr,min,sec;
  float call_dur;
  char status[15];
};

main()

{
   node *rear=NULL;
   node *front=NULL;
   node *queue;
   char ch;
   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("mobile_numbers.txt","r");
   while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
      fseek(fp,-1,1);
      fscanf(fp,"%d %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s %d", &queue->num, &queue->dd, &queue->mm, &queue->yy, &queue->hr, &queue->min, &queue->sec, queue->status, &queue->call_dur);
    }

    if(front==NULL)
      front=queue;
    else
      rear->next=queue;
    rear=queue;
    queue->next=NULL;
  }

fclose(fp);

while(queue!=NULL) {
    printf("%d %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s %d",queue->num, queue->dd, queue->mm, queue->yy, queue->hr, queue->min, queue->sec, queue->status, queue->call_dur);
    queue=queue->next;
}
```

But this isn't giving required results? Can anyone suggest a better method or see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: ayushi it would be same as if you read any file in c https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=read+and+print+from+file+in+c&oq=read+and+print+from+file+in+c&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.83982.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.iWgCkAWSlLw

Comment: i tried this                                                                                      fscanf(fp,"%d\t%d-&d-%d\t%d:%d:%d\t%s\t%1f",&queue->num,&queue->dd,&queue->mm,&queue->yy,&queue->hr,&queue->min,&queue->sec,queue->status,&queue->call_dur);                                                           to store data in a linked list .But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Not sure what you want to do with the data, but this prints to screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define MAXARG 20

FILE *f1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char FileName[MAXARG];
    char line[MAXLINE];

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage - reads FileName and prints\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(FileName, *++argv);
    }

    f1 = fopen(FileName, "r");

    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, f1)) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

NB: to call it, you have to type the program name followed by the name of your file.

If instead you want to run through and save data for parsing, try this (re-appropriated version of [C read space-separated values from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036686/c-read-space-separated-values-from-file)):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct  
{  
    char status[9];
    time_t timestamp;
    long int number;
    int duration_mins; 
    time_t call_time;
} Call; 

void dump_call(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Call *c);
int inputLine(FILE *fp, Call *c);

enum { MAXCALL = 100 };

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];
    Call calls[MAXCALL];

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCALL && inputLine(stdin, &calls[i]) != 0; i++)
        dump_call(stdout, "Call", &calls[i]);
    return 0;
}

int inputLine(FILE *fp, Call *c)
{  
    struct tm tm;
    // time_t epoch;
    int out;
    char temp[20], date_temp[9], time_temp[9];;
    if ((out = fscanf(fp, "%ld %s %s %s %d", 
        &c->number, date_temp, time_temp, c->status, &c->duration_mins)) == 5) {
        sprintf(temp, "%s %s", date_temp, time_temp);
        if ( strptime(temp, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm) != NULL )
            c->timestamp = mktime(&tm);
        return -1;
        }
    return 0;
}

void dump_call(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Call *c)  
{  
    char date_time[20];
    strftime(date_time, 20, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&(c->timestamp)));
    fprintf(fp, "%s: %-10ld %-24s %-17s %3d\n",  
               tag, c->number, date_time, c->status, c->duration_mins);
}
```

This time, to call it, type name of program followed by `<` and then name of data file; i.e:

```
read.exe < test_mobil.dat
```

Hope this helps mate - I've learnt quite a bit as well - so thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks,it worked.But what if i have to store data in a linked list and compare status(missed,outgoing,incoming) to form another linked list corresponding to status.That's why i tried storing it in a linked list using fscanf.

Comment: OK. I've worked on a better solution for you and added to my answer - let me know if this helps.

Comment: this is a big help.Thanks.

Comment: If it's what you're looking for, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer -- 
[How to read specifically formatted data from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689747/how-to-read-specifically-formatted-data-from-a-file)

I believe it'll answer your question..

Comment: should be a comment